# Add a headline after applying for a job about what these other jobs are

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

After applying for a job, you are redirected to a page confirming this with a filtered result set of jobs.  What is this filtered result set?  Can we provide a headline for why or how these jobs were then catered to me?

In this case after applying I get 10 results?

What are these results?
[image]